# Oracle remote connection through firewall KO

Tags: oracle, proxy, listener, firewall

We are using Windows 2012 R2 and Oracle 12.1.0.2. Database are in a GRID cluster but this won't affect our problem.

We just wanted to connect to a database from a "company A" network to a "company B" (which host the dbs) network and we are getting an error: IO error: network adapter could not establish the connection (sqldev output)

We opened network connection (input/output) on listener port 1521 on company A and B firewall.
And we can see connection trace on company B firewall.
We don't see anything on listener.log but i m not sure about information I should look for in this file (because i wont see the public AND final IP address of company A).

With this type of connection, is there any special parameter to set on the database/listener... side?

For information, in the KEY_Ora_GI12Home1 Windows registry (for both server) we created a new key called USE_SHARED_SOCKET with value "TRUE".

Comment: Can you access the listener port from your client-node? clientnode>netcat dbhost port ? or clientnode>telnet dbhost port ?

Comment: It's not just port 1521.  That port is _only_ used to send the initial connection request to the listener. When the listener processes the request, it either spawns a dedicated server and tells the client to communicate with that process over a 'random high port', or tells the client to communicated with a shared server dispatcher over a different port.  I'm not a net engineer, so don't know the details, but do know that there is a firewall config to allow these other ports to be used when the comm on them is initiated by the server.

Comment: @EdStevens You are absolutely correct. Corporate FW like PaloAlto group oracle communication into "application=oracle". This takes care of initial listener comm. in addition to high-port comm. But still first thing first. We need a success from the listener port utilizing nc -vz dbnode port (nc isn't available on all distros then use netcat or telnet)

Comment: Hi everyone, first thanks for your feedback! So i can confirm that communication is ok because telnet is ok and, i can see in my listener.log my connections tests: "25-NOV. -2020 10:33:43 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=SQL Developer)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=xxxxxx))(SERVICE_NAME=xMybddx)) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=xxxx)(PORT=55632)) * establish * xxxxx * 0" So, i have to allow the range of "high-port". As they seems to be dynamics, wich kind of rules we have to create on BOTH fw ?

Comment: Hi all,
High range port has been opened on each firewall, and error still there (IO... vendor code 17002).
But i performed an other test and got very suprised by the result...
I executed a test connect on my CONTAINER db and connection were successfull!

So my problem is that PLUGGABLE database connections are KOs when i connect trought proxy (cause i can connect to this pluggable when i am in the same network).

I am reading on internet but still no have serious answer..

If you have got any ideas :)

Thank you in advance.